# Does running `drush rf` detect needed updates by look at the version of files on disk or by an entry in the database?

Tags: drush, updating

Does running `drush rf` detected needed updates by looking at the version of files on disk or by an entry in the database?

We run in a load balancer, fail over situations on a some production server. Databases are one-way replicated. If the primary is updated first (and database entries are replicated over), could an update be skipped on the secondary (backup) installation?